# Can I recreate next-auth v4 session on the client side in iframe?

Tags: next.js, microsoft-teams, next-auth, samesite, microsoft-teams-js

**Situation**:

1. Nextjs web application running in iframe cannot access auth provider to let user login.
2. Nextjs web application opens a popup window, loads same web application sign-in page and then redirects to auth provider (Microsoft Azure AD).
3. User successfully authenticates (we use next-auth v4) in the popup window and is redirected back to the web application.

**Problem**: how to pass session data from the popup to the iframe, before we auto close the popup window?

Our iframe is part of MS Teams app, so Teams SDK offers a callback to pass a string value back to the iframe.

**Question**: is it possible to serialise session (cookies?) into a string and then restore it in the iframe? Given that session cookie is `httpOnly`, `secure` and `sameSite=Lax`.

I expect to enable user authentication to web application when it's running inside and outside MS Teams tab app. I would like to keep next-auth as server side auth solution, however I am OK to rebuild auth solution...

p.s. cookies `sameSite=none` would work, but this is not acceptable from security point of view.

Comment: Please refer these documentation once: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-overview  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-tab  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-oauth-provider